# Can't install Ruby or Rails using RVM : ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

Here is what I ran:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

I have xCode 4 installed. And I am running OSX 10.6.7

Here is the error I get

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/jac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/jac/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/jac/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Here are the last parts of the log file

```
checking for working volatile... yes
checking whether right shift preserve sign bit... yes
checking read count field in FILE structures... _r
checking read buffer ptr field in FILE structures... _p
checking size of struct stat.st_ino... SIZEOF_LONG
checking whether _SC_CLK_TCK is supported... yes
checking stack growing direction on i386... -1
checking for backtrace... yes
checking whether ELF binaries are produced... no
checking whether OS depend dynamic link works... yes
checking for strip... strip
configure: error: thread model is missing
```

I'll tell ya I never post question anywhere because I can usually figure stuff out eventually. But I am not seeing anyone having this specific error anywhere.  I see similar things about not having XCode... But I have that.

EDIT:
I ran into this problem because I thought I had everything set up but when I tried to make a new project I ran into this:
rails new demo

/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [rake-0.8.7, rake-0.8.7] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in`to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1195:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `/usr/include/pthread.h` on your system?

Comment: Why would I be missing `pthreads`? It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: I misread you response ... yes, if you have the header than configure should find it

Comment: Also, you're not using RVM. that is using the SYSTEM'S ruby and NOT rvm. You need to actually select a ruby to use (rvm use 1.9.2-p290) and create and use a gemset (rvm --create use 1.9.2-p290@mygemset) and also select a default ruby and gemset (rvm --create use 1.9.2-p290@mygemset --default). Please also make sure you followed the *entire* install information from rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ and NOT some external tutorial you found on the net. Then you need to populate your gemset with at least bundler such as rvm 1.9.2-p290@global exec gem install bundler && gem install rails

Comment: One last note, make sure you are using Xcode 4.1 and NOT Xcode 4.2 as Xcode 4.2 is still pre-release and doesn't compile a lot of things correctly (Apple still has it as a developer's preview). Note that RVM does NOT support its use.

Comment: @deryldoucette I have xcode 4.0.2 I am just trying to do ruby install 1.9.2-p290 and it is throwing an error. The install of Ruby with RVM is throwing the error.